# Difference between two approaches to solving least squares

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

So if you're trying to find the least squares solution to minimize $||Ax - b||^2$, the normal approach is the pseudoinverse: $A^T Ax = A^T b$.

If we define $r$ as the residual $(Ax - b)$, then we can set up another system of equations: 
$$
M =\begin{pmatrix}
        I & A \\
        U^T & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$
$$
v = 
\begin{pmatrix}
        r \\
        x \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$
$$
c = 
\begin{pmatrix}
        b \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

Then we can set up the system of equations $Mv = c$, and use this to solve for both $x$ and $r$ at the same time.

In the special case where $U = A$, $M$ is symmetric.

My question is, do these two approaches give the same result, and if not, how do they differ?

Comment: What is the $U$ matrix you've used here?

Comment: Honestly I don't know.  I came across this formula but the context didn't have any explanation for what U is.  I was hoping someone more familiar with the topic could shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we define $U=A$ as you mentioned in the question, then the two approaches are equivalent.

---

From your definition of the residuals $r$, we have

$$Ax - b = r$$

$$Ax + r = b$$

$$A^TAx + A^Tr = A^Tb$$

Stating $A^TAx = A^Tb$ is equivalent to stating $A^Tr = 0$. Both equations are just different ways of expressing a least-squares solution.

Writing the following matrix equation

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
        I & A \\
        A^T & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
        r \\
        x \\
        \end{pmatrix}
 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
        b \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

Is merely defining the residuals as $r = Ax - b$ and then requiring that $A^Tr=0$. Substitution will show you that this is equivalent to $A^TAx = A^Tb$.

Comment: Thanks!  That makes sense.  Could you maybe shed some light on the general case, when $U \neq A$?  My intuition tells me that U is a matrix which defines the objective function being optimized, so for some other $U$ it will minimize not the square of the residuals, but some other function.  Am I on the right track?